# How to split single column into 2 columns by delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following schema

```
a   |   b   |   c
qqq | www   | ddd/ff
fff | ggg   | xx/zz
jjj | gwq   | as/we
```

How would I write a query so my data comes as

```
a   |   b   | c_1 | c_2
qqq |  www  | ddd | ff
```

Comment: Will the data always be 2 parts in column c? Is the delimiter always a forward slash? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, delimiter is always a forward slash and it will always be in 2 parts, no need to handle for non 2-part columns as I would want the query to fail.   I tried `STRING_SPLIT(c, '/')` from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 but it says `STRING_SPLIT` is not found

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @test acc, `STRING_SPLIT` is only available in SQL Server 2016 and later. What version are you using?

Comment: @MikeBruesch SQL Server 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on posting a _question_. You seem to have left that part out, along with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @t table(a varchar(20),b varchar(20),c varchar(20))
    insert into @t values('qqq','www','ddd/ff')

SELECT  a, b, 
        left(c,charindex('/',c)-1) As c_1,
        right(c,charindex('/',reverse(c))-1) As c_2 
FROM @t
```

or, if column c does not always have the format xxx/yyy, you need to validate charindex position:

```
declare @t table(a varchar(20),b varchar(20),c varchar(20))
    insert into @t values('qqq','www','ddd/ff'), ('qqq','www','dddff')

SELECT  a, b, 
        case when charindex('/',c) > 0 then left(c,charindex('/',c)-1) else c end As c_1,
        case when charindex('/',c) > 0 then right(c,charindex('/',reverse(c))-1) else null end As c_2 
FROM @t
```

Comment: Hi, one issue with this is that the delimiter is coming on the both columns of the split, it shouldn't come on either.  For example  `qqq|www|ddd/ff` is coming as `qqq|www|ddd/|/ff` ideally it would come as `qqq|www|ddd|ff`

Comment: Now throws invalid length parameter passed to left / right function

Comment: Edited with executable code.
Do you have any row with column c in a format other than xxx / yyyy?

Comment: Thanks works now.. I missed one column that was malformed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as follows :

```
select LEFT(name, CHARINDEX('/', name)-1) from test_table;
```

where it returns the left part of the string name, before slash, and  the following command returns the right part, after slash.

```
select RIGHT(name, CHARINDEX('/', name)-1) from test_table;
```

I did a whole example as you can see:

```
create table test_table ( name varchar(50), substr1 varchar(50), substr2 varchar(50));

insert into test_table(name) values ('sub1/sub2');

update test_table set substr1 =
(select LEFT(name, CHARINDEX('/', name)-1) from test_table);

update test_table set substr2 =
(select RIGHT(name, CHARINDEX('/', name)-1) from test_table);

select * from test_table;
```

The result is :

```
name      | substr1 | substr2
sub1/sub2 | sub1    | sub2
```

Answer (score 0):

Patindex can also be used instead of Charindex

```
SELECT a,b,LEFT(c,PATINDEX('%/%',c)-1), RIGHT(c,PATINDEX('%/%',REVERSE(c))-1) FROM @t
```